# If the size of my stack is exceeded, how do I automatically adjust it? C++

Tags: c++, automation, stack, stack-overflow, stack-size

So I have a class CStack using the LIFO(Last in First out) method. Using standard variables `bottom/top/size` and methods like `push/pop/full/empty/print`. This is a `char` stack.

My question is, if I am adding something to this stack, when it is full, how can I automatically adjust the size? I have thought of the  `memcpy()` method but I don't really understand how it works (yet).

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
class CStack {
private:
    char *bottom_;
    char *top_;
    int size_;
public:

    CStack(int n = 20) {
        bottom_ = new char[n];
        top_ = bottom_;
        size_ = n;
    }

    void push(char c) {
        *top_ = c;
        top_++;
    }

    int num_items() {
        return (top_ - bottom_);
    }

    char pop() {
        top_--;
        return *top_;
    }

    int full() {
        return (num_items() >= size_);
    }

    int empty() {
        return (num_items() <= 0);
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "Stack currently holds " << num_items() << " items: ";
        for (char *element = bottom_; element < top_; element++) {
            cout << " " << *element;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    ~CStack() { // stacks when exiting functions 
        delete [] bottom_;
    }
};
```

Comment: If you want to keep all the elements contiguous in memory, you have to allocate a new, larger array, copy the old one and then delete the original one.

Comment: But note that your code is not idiomatic C++: `new char[n]` creates an array of `n` elements, but what you really want is an *empty* stack with *no* elements. It's time to separate memory from objects.

Comment: So I cant do it this way?

Comment: @KerrekSB it's OK; `vector.reserve()` does a similar thing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `reserve()` gets memory without creating objects... in a sense, studying `std::vector<int>` in detail teaches you about 95% of C++... :-)

Comment: One simple solution would be to use `std::vector<char>` as the store. If this sounds like cheating, consider it is in fact the default for `std::stack`. Each class should be a minimal abstraction over a more basic abstraction, except for the simplest of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. It doesn't handle exceptions but I guess you haven't got that far in your course yet?

```
void push(char c) {
    int used = top - bottom;
    if (used >= size_) {
        // grow the stack
        char* newBottom = new char[used + 20];
        memcpy(newBottom, bottom_, used * sizeof(char));
        top_ = newBottom + used;
        size_ = used + 20;
        delete[] bottom_;
        bottom_ = newBottom;        
    }
    *top_ = c;
    top_++;
}
```

Comment: `std::copy(bottom_, top_, newBottom);` is preferable to `memcpy`. As well as allowing the compiler to do type-checking, it is easier for the compiler to optimize, and it will keep working if OP expands his stack to store types with constructors instead of just `char`s.

Comment: for OP: Thinking about what happens when the stack grows big: `ptrdiff_t` is the proper type for `used`; this may be able to store more values than `int`. Preferably the stack itself should store a size as `size_t` rather than storing `top`, since `size_t` can have a bigger range than `ptrdiff_t`. Finally, we should check that `used+20` isn't going to exceed the range of `used`.

Comment: @mattmcnab yes of course, but if were going to use the STL then this entire class is redundant, right?

Comment: not necessarily as he may want behaviour that differs from `std::stack`.  If by "the STL" you mean `std::copy` , lol. `std::copy` is in the same boat as `std::memcpy`, it's just an improvement.

Comment: I want to keep it simple really with this format and a solution that fits in it. I havent used vectors yet but I could look into it I think. I just started learning c++, with Java experience (student level). Anyway I will try this one, thanks guys

Comment: In that case, Matt's point is a very good one. The reason that std::copy is better than memcpy is that it behaves well when the  items you are copying are objects. It's tempting to put up a new implementation of the class in order to get you thinking on the right track in terms of code safety early on. If that's interesting to you I'm happy to send you something.

Comment: I would appreciate that as it would help